# Android orientação (PORTRAIT/LANDSCAPE) addTextChangedListener

Tags: android, orientation

estou com um problema no momento em que meu App muda sua orientação de PORTRAIT para LANDSCAPE ou vice-versa. Testei meu código e identifiquei que o problema está nas linhas de comando onde estão os "editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {...});". Se eu as removo, o App funciona normalmente, mas quando as coloca aparece exceção de inflar minha classe.

Reparem no LOG de erro, Assim que eu mudo a orientação (linha 5) o Android consegue executar o método onActivityCreated(), mas finaliza ai.

Pelo que pude perceber em minhas buscas, quando eu troco a orientação o Android cria novamente todos os fragments, desde o método onAttach() até o onActivityCreated(), depois faz a mesma coisa com as classes pais, assim por diante, e só depois ele vai para os métodos seguintes (onStart(), etc).

Gostaria de tentar resolver isso, pois o TextWatcher me ajuda muito no App, não queria criar outra solução sendo que já existe uma...

```
05-14 02:02:19.635: D/onDestroy(12870): TESTE - TimesFragment
05-14 02:02:19.635: D/onDestroy(12870): TESTE - ChangeHoursFragment
05-14 02:02:19.830: D/onCreateView(12870): TESTE ClockFragment
05-14 02:02:19.830: D/onCreateView(12870): TESTE - TimesFragment
05-14 02:02:19.909: D/onActivityCreated(12870): TESTE - TimesFragment
05-14 02:02:19.987: D/AndroidRuntime(12870): Shutting down VM
05-14 02:02:19.987: W/dalvikvm(12870): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e331f8)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.lft.app/br.lft.app.appViewPager}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class fragment
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1976)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3371)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:129)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4516)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class fragment
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at br.lft.app.AppFragment.onCreateView(AppFragment.java:24)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1135)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4655)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1949)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    ... 12 more
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at br.lft.app.TimesFragment.calculateExtras(TimesFragment.java:225)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at br.lft.app.TimesFragment$6.onTextChanged(TimesFragment.java:107)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8054)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3429)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3282)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:95)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3257)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3127)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:10030)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:10008)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:425)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:304)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    ... 26 more
```

Obs.: já tentei colocar todo o conteúdo do onCreateView() para onActivityCreated(), mas não adiantou.

Answer (score 1):

Quando há uma mudança de direção o TextWatcher está sendo executado, já que o texto provavelmente estava preenchido e quando gira não está mais. Se você observar está tentando pegar uma string vazia e converter para inteiro, o que faz o aplicativo quebrar. Basta colocar um Try Catch para tratar essa situação.

Erro:

> 05-14 02:02:20.049: E/AndroidRuntime(12870): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Solução:

```
try{
    //TODO tenta converter a string para int
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //TODO não conseguiu converter a string para int
}
```